# javascript setInterval function and cronjob

Tags: javascript, setinterval

The goal is to runs a code inside an interval function

```
setInterval(function {/* do something */}, 50000)
```

when a cron-job runs each 15 minutes for triggering `test.php`

In my code, I have a `setInterval` function in which runs the code at an interval time `50 seconds`. However when I run my code on a localhost server manually (instead of running it by a cron-job) and close the browser window before interval time (`50 seconds`) at my file location `localhost/test.php` then the code inside interval function won't run!.

However if the browser window is open then the code inside interval runs. I am wondering if this is because of localhost server and if I trigger the code by setting up a `cron-job` on a live server then the code inside interval function will run despite the fact that there is no browser window on a live server to be open or close when the cron-job runs. Is that true or am I missing something?

Comment: Are you expecting a setInterval to keep running after the browser window that started it is closed?  Also as a side note, setInterval is **not** jQuery.

Comment: You can't run client-side javascript from cron. Is your javascript for setinterval running in node.js?

Comment: @Taplar. No I will add a `clearinterval` to stop it............................................ @Brian Glaz. No it is not running in node.js. it runs inside jquery

Comment: I don't understand why you keep saying jquery.  And any setInterval started in a browser will be terminated when the browser is closed.

Comment: jQuery is a library, not a language, and `setInterval` is not part of that library.  It's built into JavaScript.

Comment: javascript doesnt work the way you seem to think it does. Javascript in a web page will only run while that webpage is open. Close the page and the javasricpt ceases execution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a cron job that executes some php frequently, like every minute.
The php can check if it’s schedule time.  If so execute your task.  If not, quit and wait until cron kicks in in another minute to re check the schedule.  The amount of server load caused by checking a date/time once/minute will be minimal.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to run JavaScript's `setInterval` through a CRON, using PHP.

`setInterval` is a JavaScript function and normally runs through a browser*.
The browser receives the output of the PHP script and then runs the JavaScript that came with it.
As soon as the browser window/tab that spawned the interval is closed, the interval is destroyed.

CRON, not being a browser, doesn't care at all at what is the output of the script it runs.
It just happens that there is some JavaScript in the output but nothing else happens with it.

*If you want to run JavaScript on the server-side you might want to read about Node.js

..also setInterval is not a jQuery function - it's native JavaScript.

Comment: Is there a solution for doing that and not using Node.js? My goal is to run a task (code) at an exact time that the task has been scheduled and I want to run a cron-job every 15 minutes (instead of every second or minutes) to save server cpu (I might be wrong about running a cron-job every second might slow down the server!). I though I can calculate the differences between cron-job and the schedule tast and run a `setInterval function ` that runs at the differences time between them. Kindly let me know if there is a better and simple way to do it by using php?

Comment: you'd need to find a way to do what your javascript does using PHP. It should be possible (whatever it is) but it's hard to blind guess.